# React Hooks: Transition don't work with Node as Prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a Dropdown made with React Hooks. The button should have Arrow, which rotate. My first Version works fine:

```
 const DropdownMenu= (props) => {
      const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
      const openDropdown = (): void => setOpen(prevState => !prevState);

      return (
        <div>
          <Button
            onClick={openDropdown}
            dropdownIsOpen={open}
          >
Text </Button>
          <DropdownContent isOpen={isOpen} />
        </div>
      );
    };

    export default DropdownMenu;

const Button = (props) => {
  return (
    <Button Click={props.onClick}>
        Text
        <Arrow rotate={props.dropdownIsOpen} color={designTheme.color.primary} />
    </Button>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

But now I have multiple Dropdowns and want to use them with the same component. I gave the toggleNode as prop. Now the Arrow rotate but without the transition:

```
const DropdownButton = (props) => {
  const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const onToggle = (): void => setOpen(prevState => !prevState);
  return (
    <Dropdown
      isOpen={props.isOpen}
      onToggle={onToggle}
      toggleNode={
        <Button dropdownIsOpen={isOpen}>
          Text
        </Button>
      }
    />
  );
};

export default DropdownButton;
```

Have someboy an idea?

Thank you!

Comment: What is `DropDown`? Please include its code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my fault.

In my Dropdown component I render two different states conditional. So it renders the start or the end state and don't use the animation. I have to render a animation and don't render new when I click so the animation works.

Answer (score 0):

my guess is, you are exporting different `Button`

How can you use `Button` inside `Button`, possibly by importing `Button` from somewhere  else. And then you are again exporting `Button`. This will be confuse for transpiler, as which `Button` to be exported.

**You might want to rename your custom Button to something else**

```
const Button = (props) => {
  return (
    <Button Click={props.onClick}>
        Text
        <Arrow rotate={props.dropdownIsOpen} color={designTheme.color.primary} />
    </Button>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your `Button` component takes an `onClick` prop:

```
const Button = (props) => {
  return (
    <Button Click={props.onClick}>
        Text
        <Arrow rotate={props.dropdownIsOpen} color={designTheme.color.primary} />
    </Button>
  );
};
```

**NOTE:** As @SagarMore points out, there my also be a naming collision between *some* imported `Button` component and *your* `Button` component.

You may just need to pass a callback to `Click` (terrible name, BTW, should be `onClick`, hopefully it was just a typo):

```
const DropdownButton = (props) => {
  const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const onToggle = (): void => setOpen(prevState => !prevState);
  return (
    <Dropdown
      isOpen={props.isOpen}
      onToggle={onToggle}
      toggleNode={
        <Button onClick={onToggle} dropdownIsOpen={isOpen}>
          Text
        </Button>
      }
    />
  );
};
```

Passing `onToggle` to the inner button's onClick handler *should* now toggle the `isOpen` state of the `DropDown`.